# How to check if the user Active(1) or not using passport(node.js)?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have written logic for logging in, the user is able to login through email or (mobile) phone number. It is working fine, but I need to verify another field while the user is logging in.

If the user email/phone number is already existing, then I need to check whether the user is Active value '0' or '1' .if its '0' user not verified that time i need to send err message you are not verified yet .it its '1' then user able to continue the process

Active means :

Active : 1

How can i do that?

My User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  mobilenumber: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
  },
  Active: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '0',
    },

});
```

Passport :

```
exports.setup = function (User, config) {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password' // this is the virtual field on the model
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
         var criteria = (email.indexOf('@') === -1) ? {
                 mobilenumber: email
            } : {
                 email: email
             };
      User.findOne(criteria, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'This email or mobilenumber is not registered.' });
        }
        if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'This password is not correct.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));
};
```

My controller:

```
exports.show = function (req, res, next) {
  var userId = req.params.id;

  User.findById(userId, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    res.json(user.profile);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If authentication succeeds, you should save some info about user in the session, and then you can check if the id of the user exists or not.

In your `AuthController.js` or whatever controller you are using,

```
    usr = req.user.auth_data;
    //check if the user already exists with that id.
    if ( req.user.user_data.id ) {
      UserInfo.findOne ( {user_id:req.user.user_data.id} ).exec(function (err,userDetails){
        if (err) {
          return res.send ( {error:err} );
        } else if (!req.user.user_data.email) {
          return res.view ('form/email');
        } else if (!userDetails) {
          // we have phone number already available
          return res.redirect('/profile');
        } else {   
          return res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }
      });
    } else {
    //its a new user show user a form for entrering the minimal necessary details.
      return res.view('form/emailphone',{ userDetails : req.user.user_data });
    }
```

Also create a policy which checks for pages allowed only after logging in, so if a user's session expires in between, it can be redirected to the home page.

Comment: where i need to change my code paaport or controller function @Viral

Comment: user exsist or not that one already done but i need to verify whether that user active value 0 or 1 or not